# How to enforce SBT to always fetch sources for project dependencies?

Tags: scala, sbt

Just getting started with SBT, and I would like to setup it up to **always** get sources for dependencies it downloads. Having to add to remember to type `withSources()` for every dependency declared is only mildly annoying, but the real killer is the [dependencies of dependencies problem](http://groups.google.com/group/simple-build-tool/browse_thread/thread/c747e733b150ccf1/2c3fd8eaefc0696b).

Anybody know a simple switch to turn this on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this https://github.com/OlegYch/sbt-sources-plugin

Comment: I'm guessing this only works for pre-0.10 versions of sbt, or at least the readme file instructions look to be specific to that. Is that the case? Is there going to be an update for 0.10?

Comment: this is not needed anymore for 0.10, since there is update-classifiers and update-sbt-classifiers, and also some built-in support in sbt-idea, although it was buggy last time i tried

Comment: For whomever reads this and is still lost (like me): "update-classifiers" is just an sbt command. Execute it and it will download all javadocs and sources for all dependencies.

Comment: thanks @jsalvata for the clarification, I was in the same camp :)